# Error in creating an array that converts Strings to Doubles and stores them

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a code that given a sequence, (private double[] sequence mentioned earlier in the code defining a sequence), will seperate the strings into an array and then assign the string values into doubles using the Double.parseDouble. The results i get from println are so strange though.

When i enter "2,3,4" as the value for s, the result displays as:
s: 2,3,4
result: [D@1d733e1

This is my code:

```
...
    public Sequence(String s)
         {                      
              String[] tokens = s.split(","); 
              System.out.println("s: " + s);
              double[] result = new double[tokens.length]; 

              int i = 0; 
             for(String token:tokens){ 
                                     result[i++] = Double.parseDouble(token);
                                   }
               System.out.println("result: " + result);
           } 
    }
```

And i don't know why it's outputting those strange results.

Following this method, i created another method to determine if the values inside the array are equal to each other. This is the code i used for it:

```
public boolean allEqual()
   {double name = sequence[0];
for(int i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++){
          if(sequence[i] != name){
                 return false;
                }
          name = sequence[i];
        }
      return true;
```

And this code keeps saying that the array index is out of bounds: 0 and i feel like it has something to do with my first code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When does your `allEqual()` throw the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException? Could you elaborate on what steps are taken, and a more detailed desciption of your `Sequence` class?

Comment: All good! I completely solved it now. Thank you for your help about viewing arrays! That was useful knowledge!

The error in my code was that i had to write that 
sequence = result;

Then i could call in the sequence variable in later methods and have the correct array values assigned to it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print an array meaningfully, use the `Arrays.toString(result)` method. For your code:

```
System.out.println("result: " + Arrays.toString(result));
```

This needs to be done because the default `toString()` implementation of all primitive `array` objects gives the ugly output you see above. It has *some* meaning, but in general you will never want to print it out or log it anywhere.

If you use a static code analysis tool like `FindBugs`, it will warn you about these types of things. http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks, it displays fine now :)

Do you know anything about my second part of the code, and why it isn't working? There is another code i use to check to see if my code is working and it says that it isn't. The Arrayindexisoutofbounds: 0 error appears everytime.

@Kon

Comment: Ah no worries, I solved it!

I had to list that the sequence = result; at the end of the first code.

Comment: @Lang_lang Glad you solved it yourself, sorry I didn't see your comment until now.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `System.out.println("result: " + result);` you are asking Java to print out an object, but `result` is an array which doesn't have a default `toString()` method, so what it shows is the object's reference, which is not meaningful to the human eye.  As mentioned by @Kon you should be more explicit about how you want the data to show up.